# XMLHttpRequest() json parallel multiple threads

Tags: javascript, multithreading

I am new to javascripts

please help me to solve this,

I have a function for db trip. that fires on every 10 mili seconds. problem is data is varying some time it gives 3 records sometime 5 records. there is not an issue of sp parameters I have passed. I think it's due to the function call which is not a thread. so process of function call is overlapping before the previous call complete

I have seen article for multi threading
https://gist.github.com/johdax/1269740

but don't have idea to integrate my function with threading.

this is my function

```
<script>
    setInterval(function(){UserList()},10);

    function UserList()
        {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp6=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp6=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp6.onreadystatechange=function()
            {
                if (xmlhttp6.readyState==4 && xmlhttp6.status==200)
                {
                    $("#UserStatusList").html(xmlhttp6.responseText);
                }
            }
            var a = $('#cmbProjectList').val();
            if (a==null){  a=""}

            xmlhttp6.open("GET","UserList.asp?ProjectId=" +  a,true);
            xmlhttp6.send();
            return false;
        }
```

please help me to solve this.
how can I apply threading on this?

Comment: JavaScript is not `Multithreaded` but can be `Asynchronus`...

Comment: 10 milisecond interval is not really possible...

Comment: If you don't want the requests to overlap try increasing the delay or make it `synchronus` by setting the last parameter of `open` method to `false` instead of `true`

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't really use threads in any exposed way, AFAIK. If you wanted something truly off the normal browser flow, you could look into the Web Worker API which makes a separate sandbox for JS activities.